# Switch-case command after break executes

Tags: c, switch-statement, message

I have a C Win32 program

There is a message handler function that has switch-case statements to handle messages.

There is one phenomenon that amazed me ... I will try to explain in simple words.

```
switch (Message)
{
case 0:
    printf("Case 0 \n");
    break;
case 1:
    printf("Case 1 \n");
    break;
    printf("After Break Case 1 \n");
case 2:
     switch( WHAT_SC(wParam) ) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
           if (KEYBOARD_UNLOCKED()) {
             defstatus = DefWindowProc(hWnd, iMessage, wParam, lParam);
           }
           break;
        case 3:
           if (bLockWindowSize) {
              return (TRUE);
           }
        default:
            defstatus = DefWindowProc(hWnd, iMessage, wParam, lParam);
            break;
    }
    break;
    HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, Func_OC);
case 3:
    printf("Case 3 \n");
    break;
    printf("After Break Case 3 \n");
default :
    printf("default \n");
    break;
    printf("After Break default \n");
}
```

(The above code is just pseudo code )
At some point the command after the break gets executed.
i.e.

```
 HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, Func_OC);
```

Why / how is that ?

Thanks

Comment: Is that on the debug or release version?

Comment: It should not if the previous break is really relative to the outer switch case (i.e. there is not an extra for loop of something like that). Can you post the real code ?

Comment: Why you have statement after `break`? Did not compiler gave warning of unreachable code? Change the warning-level to the highest level (/W4).

Comment: pseudo code is not enough!

Comment: Are you sure that `HANDLE_MSG` gets executed from this code? Does callstack verifies this?

Comment: Hi Cup - Release. ~~ Hi Nicholas - I am really sorry I cant do that but I assure you there is no outer Loop. ~~ Hello dBasic - Didnt give warning, but yes I will try that (dont know where the option is in VS 2008)

Comment: Hi dBasic - Yes Call Stack verifies and my BreakPoint hits.

Comment: Post the real code. The bug is most likely a very trivial one caused by goofing up the break statements.

Comment: Are you sure that line is getting executed or is the same function from somewhere else being called?

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEM RESOLVED ...

The

```
 HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, Func_OC);
```

Gets executed here because of the following reason

HANDLE_MSG( is a MACRO. 
when i looked into the definition of that, i see the following code in  WindowsX.h

```
 #define HANDLE_MSG(hwnd, message, fn)    \
     case (message): return HANDLE_##message((hwnd), (wParam), (lParam), (fn))
```

What happens is that, the macro HANDLE_MSG in the switch case .. gets replaced with the code in WindowxS.h

This acts as another case, hence gets executed with a return.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.

(Cup and dBase deserve a Special thanks)

Regards
:( A clueless programmer

Comment: This still doesnt solve your question, " (The above code is just pseudo code ) At some point the command after the break gets executed. i.e.

 HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, Func_OC);"

Comment: Read the Question carefully The command after the Break gets executed at times ....... i.e. when that condition is true. It ACTS as another case.

Comment: You might like to accept your own answer, so this gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

This can only happen if the break statement is braking any loop inside switch or other switch case inside switch case.

If you see

```
 HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, Func_OC);
```

is getting executed then  "case 3 " must execute.